# Debug ASP.NET web forms in full IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2013

I'm running Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate on a Windows 8.1 (with Update 1) laptop, and I would like to debug an ASP.NET web forms project against IIS, which is installed on the local Windows 8.1 instance.

Previous versions of Visual Studio had an option to use IIS Express or full IIS, but I cannot find that option in the Project properties anymore.

How do I deploy & debug my ASP.NET web forms project in full IIS?

EDIT: When I right-click on my project, I see this:

[image: Right-click context menu]

And then if I click on "Properties Window" I see this:

[image]

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. I created a new VS2013 C# ASP.NET web forms project, and I'd like to debug/deploy it to IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just double checked one of my local Web Forms applications locally running in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate on Windows 8.1. The settings are still there. If you open the project properties for your Web Forms project, you should see the following:

[image: Web Project Properties Pane]

After selecting Local IIS, setting a port, and saving, you should be walked through the process of configuring a Virtual Directory for your site (if one isn't already configured).

**EDIT**

After looking at your edit, it looks like you've created a Web Site Project rather than a Web Application Project. You can read about the various differences here:

[Web Application Projects versus Web Site Projects in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you haven't written any significant code yet, I'd suggest deleting the Web Site Project and creating a new Web Application Project. You'll then see the settings as described above.

If you really want to keep the Web Site Project, you'll have to configure the site in IIS and then open it in Visual Studio using the 'Open Web Site...' dialog (and then choosing Local IIS as the source):

[image: Open Web Site Dialog]

Comment: How do I get to that Properties page? VS2013 doesn't bring that up, when I right-click the project and select Properties Window.

Comment: Thanks for the edit ... you are correct, I created a "website" instead of a "web project."

Answer (score 3):

This is one way to have your project available in IIS:

- Press Ctrl+X, type `inetmgr`

or

- Open your IIS Manager Application.
- Expand the tree on the left.
- Add WebSite
- - Give a name to the website and port
- - For file location provide the same file location were your project is.

Assuming your port number is 3000 just simply type `http://localhost:3000` in your browser.

Now from Visual Studio go to:

- file Open...
- - WebSite (you will see that IIS is available on the left).
- - Open your new web site

This will let you debug from IIS and any changes you make will be directly made on IIS as well.